# Test email piping locally

Tags: php, email, localhost, pipe, mamp

I'm using email piping to parse messages and handle them appropriately in my app.

I'd like to figure out a way to test this locally on my Macbook Pro. I use MAMP for development.

Any ideas how I can send an email to my local machine that gets piped to a script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you need to test is just a pipeline, `yourscript <samplemessage.txt` does the same thing.

Comment: Awesome. So I could just make samplemessage.txt include contents of an email message?

Comment: Yes, it should be a complete RFC822 message, as delivered to e.g.  your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

unless you really want to install a mail server on your local machine, you can't. shouldn't really be hard to set up a test environment on your hosted site.